# Bootstrap responsive design problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At the minute I'm just getting myself used to the bootstrap framework, I understand the functionality of it but I'm not able to  get the results I desire.

Simply on one row I want 2 sections side by side. First I want a div that contains nav nav-tabs which span 8 columns, then I want another div beside it containing some text with column span of 4.

Here is my code below

```
<div class= "row-fluid" id="projectTabs">
    <div class="span8">
            <br>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Favourites</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Customer</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Non-Chargeable</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Global</a></li>
            </ul>
     </div>
    <div class="span4">
        This text is enclosed in a box.

    </div>
</div>
```

I have included the following also:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Am I missing something here? As when I use this I am left with the text below the nav tabs. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using Bootstrap 2 classes but referencing the Bootstrap 3 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css you are referring is bootstrap v3.2.0 which has changed class name structure syntax.

This is correct syntax :

```
<div class= "container" id="projectTabs">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Favourites</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Customer</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Non-Chargeable</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Global</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        This text is enclosed in a box.

    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Fiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/8pjyt302/embedded/result/